# How To Find Out The Original Filename From A GZIP File In C# .Net Core Which Has Been Renamed

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzip, gzipstream

I am downloading a gzipped file from a web source and I can see from the microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-7.0) that it is fairly simple to decompress a gzip, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the original filename.

I understand that gzips don't have to store the original filename, but there is provision for doing so in the headers and I can see that in this case, the filename is likely to be in there as I can see it if I open the archive in 7Zip.

Is there a simple way in .net core to get the original filename or is the only option to somehow manually decode the gzip file headers?

(I did see a stackoverflow question like this which was self-answered, but it was from 2010 and I am wondering if anything has changed since then)

Comment: `it was from 2010` the GZipStream class hasn't changed - it's a stream, not a package class. It knows nothing about metadata  like file names just as `FileStream` knows nothing about them. It doesn't even know about packages.

Comment: The [core decoder reads the filename](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/sys/System/IO/compression/GZipDecoder.cs,163), as it's required to when parsing the header, but doesn't otherwise attempt to parse or save the filename in anyway that would allow a down stream user to see it.

Comment: wow that is so annoying, they do actually have the ability but they just don't expose it :( many thanks for that link, it was very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only option is to manually decode the gzip header. However the header format is quite simple, so this would be easy and straightforward to implement. See [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) for the specification.

Comment: i think you're right, i haven't found anything further since i made this post, ah well it's not a massive thing, it just would have been nice :)